# KStream Joins Not working in kubernetes env but is working perfectly in local

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, azure-aks

I have a simple application that would consume two streams from topicA and topicB, convert them to KTables and then join both tables using Foreign Keys. The result of the join is then send to an output topic. In the local environment the application is working perfectly but when I host it in Kubernetes, I could see that the Ktables are receiving the messages but the join is not triggering.

Im converting the KTables to Stream and consoling the key and Values and came to the conclusion that the KTables are receiving the messages. Similar logs were put before passing to the output topic and inside the ValueJoiner but to no avail. The replication factor is 1 and the application has its own group. I have also checked the internal intermediate foreign join topic and they are also empty. Could someone give some pointer on how to debug.

```
KTable<String, GenericRecord> tableA = kafkaStreamService.getKTable(
                builder,
                "TOPICA",
                tableAMapper
        );
      
        KTable<String, GenericRecord> tableB= kafkaStreamService.getKTable(
                builder,
                "TOPICB",
                tableBMapper
        );
    
        KTable<String, GenericRecord> joinedTable = tableA.leftJoin(
                tableB,
                keyExtractor,
                joiner
        );

        KStream<String,GenericRecord> joinedStream = joinedTable.toStream();
        appointmentLabDetailAndAppointmentStream.to("OUTPUT_TOPIC");
```

kafkaStreamService.getKTable takes in the stream does some processign and then converts to table using
`processedStream.toTable(Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), genericAvroSerde));`